# Permanently raising nofile limits in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ssh, cron, pam, ulimit

I cannot seem to figure out what exactly is needed to allow the maximum number of file descriptors to be raised permanently for all users.

`/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
root    hard    nofile    1500000
root    soft    nofile    1000000
root    hard    nproc     15000
root    soft    nproc     10000
*       hard    nofile    1500000
*       soft    nofile    1000000
*       hard    nproc     15000
*       soft    nproc     10000
```

I have placed the following in the `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

After a reboot, logging in as any user and issuing `ulimit -n` resulted in `1024`.

After that, I tried requiring `pam_limits.so` into every file under `/etc/pam.d`.  Rebooted.  Logged in.  No such luck.

If I issue the command `ulimit -n 1000000`, then check, the limit is set as expected.  So, I placed `@reboot ulimit -n 1000000` into `crontab -e`.  Rebooted.  Logged in.  No luck.

I checked `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and PAM is enabled.

I have tried setting the limits on every reboot with:

```
/sbin/sysctl -w fs.file-max=1000000
/sbin/sysctl -p
```

No luck.

I have a server that has a ton of concurrent traffic, and need those limits that high, because it takes the server a very long time to clear out file descriptors.  What do I have to do in order to permanently raise the file descriptor limit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I increased the number of files limits for everyone this way (segment from `/etc/security/limits.conf`):

```
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files (Doug: - so Samba will not complain)
* - nofile 16384
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
```

That was on a 12.04 server. However, I tested 100000 on my 14.04 server and it worked fine. (Edit: also checked on 20.04)

```
~/config/security$ ulimit -n
16384
```

EDIT: For most applications that is enough, but it doesn't change the default value for root:

```
# ulimit -n
1024
```

If the number also needs to be changed for root, then (2020.09.04 - I now use 131,072):

```
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open file descriptors
* - nofile 131072
root - nofile 131072
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
```

And so:

```
$ sudo su
# ulimit -n
131072
```

Comment: That still had no effect.  Did you have to place `session require pam_limits.so` anywhere?

Comment: No. I just did the edit, as sudo, and re-booted, before the ulimit was 1024 and after the ulimit on my 14.04 test server was 100000.

Comment: Simply adjusting `/etc/security/limits.conf` and reverting everything else back to stock worked.  Thanks!

Comment: No need to reboot, just logout/login.

Comment: @w3rthl3ss what does your limit.conf looks like i have same issue and reference purposes

Comment: @RizwanPatel I used the same format as the one in the question.

Comment: @w3rthl3ss please refer this https://gist.github.com/matt212/90b7e60432b561b7d8042f103e12b061

Comment: @w3rthl3ss any recommendations wanted to change my ulimit from 1864 to 2048 !

Comment: @RizwanPatel : I do not understand why your ulimit would be 1864. This answer should be what to do. If not, perhaps start a new question, detailing why your new question isn't actually a duplicate of this one. Point us to the new question, and we'll try to help.

Comment: @DougSmythies Sorry my conventional ulimit -u is 1824 and when i apply the changes  in limit.conf file and rebooted the server the value remains same !