# Too many open files

Tags: files, ulimit

when i open Lutris and then LOL client , this happening. And game never work good. I tried many things but never can change the open file limit. How can fix this ?

```
Waiting on children  
Waiting on children  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
esync: write: Bad file descriptor  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
esync: write: Bad file descriptor  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files  
eventfd: Too many open files
```

**also there is my limits info**

```
~$ ulimit -a  
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0  
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited  
scheduling priority             (-e) 0  
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited  
pending signals                 (-i) 15106  
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384  
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited  
open files                      (-n) 1024  
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8  
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200  
real-time priority              (-r) 0  
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192  
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited  
max user processes              (-u) 15106  
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited  
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606970/permanently-raising-nofile-limits-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/606987#606987)

Comment: @mchid : just tried it on a 19.10 computer. Worked fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently raising nofile limits in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606970/permanently-raising-nofile-limits-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: @DougSmythies  Okay, it seems that I had to add:  `session required pam_limits.so` at the end of my `/etc/pam.d/common-session*` file to get it to work for some reason.

Answer (score 18):

When the "Too Many Open Files" error message is written to the logs, it indicates that all available file handles for the process have been used (this includes sockets as well).

In a majority of cases, this is the result of file handles being leaked by some part of the application.
`ulimit` is a command in Unix/Linux which allows to set system limits for all properties. In your case, you need to increase the maximum number of open files to a large number (e.g. 1000000):

```
ulimit -n 1000000
```

or

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=1000000
```

and `/etc/security/limits.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.conf` change:

```
fs.file-max = 1000000
```

To determine if the number of open files is growing over a period of time, issue `lsof` to report the open files against a PID on a periodic basis. For example:

```
lsof -p [PID] -r [interval in seconds, 1800 for 30 minutes] > lsof.out
```

This is especially useful if you don't have access to the `lsof` command:

```
ls -al /proc/PID/fd
```

[Guidelines for setting ulimits](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg21469413)

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
less /proc/PID/limits
```

to check the actual Soft Limit of Max open files. If you set up ulimits but the actual number is still low - review how you launch the process. E.g., systemd takes over the ulimits, and you should use explicit settings, better at the process level, to ensure your program gets the runtime limits it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there are different cases why this might happen:

1. System wide limit (Run `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` to see the limit, for me it's `9223372036854775807`)
2. Max user instances (Run `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances`: used to be `128`)
3. Hard user limit (Run `ulimit -nH`: `1048576`)
4. Soft user limit (Run `ulimit -nS`: used to be `1024`)

### 1. System wide limit

The system wide rule can be adjusted by putting

```
fs.file-max = 9223372036854775807
```

into `/etc/sysctl.conf`. This value was no issue for me.

### 2. Max user instances

For me, this value was too low. To fix it, add or edit this line again in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 1024
```

### 3. & 4. Hard or soft user limit

My soft user limit was too low, too. To fix that, open `/etc/security/limits.conf` (as root) and add this line:

```
<username>             soft    nofile 100000
```

(Replace `<username>` with your username, or `*` for all users)

The hard user limit can be set by replacing `soft` with `hard` in the line above. Of course, you can have multiple rules for hard & soft limit or different users.

### Putting things into effect

Maybe a logout and logging back in is enough for the changes to be picked up, but I just restarted the system to be sure.