# too many open files for a Golang server running behind Caddy

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, golang

I am running a Go binary that has an http server with systemd. I have it setup so that Caddy has a reverse-proxy to this go http server.

```
http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:8002: accept4: too many open files;
dial tcp 192.85.2.4:443: socket: too many open files
```

When I look at the open files of the process, I get 1025 or less, though my ulimit is set to a much larger limit:

```
$ lsof -p 1243 | wc -l
1025
```

```
$ ulimit -Sn
200000
```

```
$ ulimit -Hn
1048576
```

I'm not sure if that's the problem but seems that it could be? Seems like the Go server should be spawning new goroutines or take care of that somehow.

EDIT: Here's my server script:

```
package main
  
import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "net/http"
)

type Config struct{}


func (c *Config) testerHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.Body.Close()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello\n")
}

func main() {
        c := &Config{}
        http.HandleFunc("/tester", c.testerHandler)
        fmt.Println("listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000")
        http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

EDIT: And here's a script I use to spam my server:

```
package main
  
import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        number := 10000
        log.Printf("spamming %d numbers\n", number)
        ch := make(chan interface{})
        client := http.Client{}

        for i:=0; i<number; i++{
                go func(number int) {
                        u := "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tester"
                        rsp, err := client.Get(u)
                        if err != nil {
                                ch <- err
                                return
                        }
                        rsp.Body.Close()

                        ch <- rsp
                }(number)
        }

        var errs int
        m := make(map[int]int)

        for i:=0; i<number; i++ {
                rsp := <-ch
                switch rsp.(type) {
                case *http.Response:
                        code := rsp.(*http.Response).StatusCode
                        m[code]++
                default:
                        log.Println(rsp.(error))
                        errs++
                }
        }

        log.Println("errs:", errs)
        for k, v := range m {
                log.Printf("%d:%d\n", k, v)
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a race condition between your test script and your server.
Your server can't open more connection because your script is already spamming it?
Check also the lsof of your spammer server as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that can be solved by modifying some parameters of your system.

I recommend that you follow the following thread: [Too many open files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182021/too-many-open-files)

Comment: Yes, I have followed that and have listed both my hard and soft limits above.

Comment: I've also added a simple server and script that reproduces the issue on a brand new server on Scaleway (4cpus/8GB ram) and have increased my ulimit. I am spamming my server with 10K requests but I still get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by either Disabling Keep Alives on the ReverseProxy or by setting a low "ReadTimeout" on the Go Server.

Simple example

```
func main(){
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr: ":8080",
    ReadTimeout:    2 * time.Second,
    Handler: http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        go fmt.Printf("handling request\n")
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, client")
    }),
}
log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Systemd takes over ulimits and sets the actual (=soft) runtime limit for max number of files to 1024. It is expected that the process takes care of requesting resources it needs explicitly - that is how most "professional" applications are written. For home grown ones, the resource can be requested in the dot-service file, e.g.,:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=10240
LimitNOFILESoft=10240
```