# Too many files open - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, mongodb

I have installed mongoDB on ubuntu 18.04. when I run my code, it starts giving me the error

```
Error connecting to 192.xx.xx.xx : Too many open files
```

I've tried to set up ulimit -a to a larger value and also running ulimit command says "unlimited".

any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: post your `/etc/security/limits.conf` contents.

Comment: this is what I have put in my /etc/security/limits.conf  *     soft   nofile  65535
*     hard   nofile  65535
mongod hard nofile 100000
mongod soft nofile 100000

Comment: It can be viewed at https://ibb.co/SdvVgWz

Comment: what do you get for `ulimit -n` ?

Comment: ulimit -n returns 1024

Comment: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606970/permanently-raising-nofile-limits-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/606987#606987) and do it that way. By the way, that answer is from years ago, I now set it to 131072.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanently raising nofile limits in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606970/permanently-raising-nofile-limits-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: you mean just to add "* - nofile 16384" in my /etc/security/limits.conf file? and remove everything else ?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: one last thing before I implement it , will it be applied to all users? I mean i am using mongodb and when I execute my code, I get this error, so will this also implement on mongod user ?

Comment: I did it the same way and rebooted my machine still ulimit -n returns 1024 :(

Comment: Post your `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

Comment: I just put * - nofile 100000 in my /etc/security/limits.conf file.

Comment: You must be running as root? You shouldn't need to adjust for root, but if you do, you have to specifically do that. see the comments at the start of the file. See "NOTE".

Comment: the note says #        - NOTE: group and wildcard limits are not applied to root.
#          To apply a limit to the root user, <domain> must be
#          the literal username root.
I am actually new to ubuntu, so I don't know how do I change it for all users?

Comment: you already changed it for all users. I am saying you shouldn't have to for root. Try your program, as a regular user

Comment: I did that and run my code, still no luck :(

Comment: I edited that [old answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606970/permanently-raising-nofile-limits-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts) showing how to also increase it for root.

Comment: tried everything, still no luck

Comment: Then I suspect your code. It might be some loop exceeding any reasonable number of open files. Perhaps post your code, or starting picking away at it trying to simplify the failure case.

Comment: my complete code can be viewed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712929/mongodb-error-connecting-to-192-xx-xx-xx-too-many-open-files